# eclipse key bindings everywhere

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to assign an eclipse key shortcut. Say, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> = "File Search".

I can assign this in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys -> File Search -> Binding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

I also need to select "When". I can select one of "Editing Java Source", "Editing Java Script Source" etc.

Is it possible to assign this key shortcut to be effective everywhere? What I mean is I can be doing anything in eclipse - editing Java, js, xml, etc or I could be in Console window looking at the logs. I will highlight a word I want to search and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and eclipse just has to bring up the "File Search" dialog.

How can we do this without have to assign the binding to every item in the "When" drop-down list?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try setting "When" to "In Windows". I just checked, and the key binding worked everywhere I tested it...

Comment: Yes it does. But not if there are conflicts. For example, in the Indigo eclipse I use Ctrl+Shift+F is bound to Format. So binding the same key to File Search brings up the File Search Dialog when the focus is in any other window. When the focus is in Java Editor, it formats the source instead. So need to unbind the conflicts. "Editing Java Sources" takes precedence over "In Windows". Thanks for the pointer though. It solved my problem!

Comment: just a note about binding conflicts: if you're filtering the list to find a command, the conflicts area will only show conflicts with commands that are included in the filter, so if you're trying to see if your chosen key has conflicts with other commands, be sure to remove the filter text after finding the command you want.