# eclipse shortcut publish everywhere

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to change the publish shortcut behaviour to apply to every window i work.

This would remove the need to be in the server view to use this shortcut (CTRL+ALT+P)

So far I followed this post: [eclipse key bindings everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054331/eclipse-key-bindings-everywhere)

Setting **"when"** to **"in windows"** did not work. I guess because the shortcut is still part of the category **"server"**

How can I change the category? Is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work. The command handler for the Publish action (`org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.view.servers.ServerActionHandler`) expects the current selection to be a server and doesn't do anything if it is not. So you have to be in the server view for it to work.

Comment: thats sad because i like to work in a maximized window, minimizing it to publish every time is annoying. thanks for your insight!

Comment: Is there any workaround or other solution? Moving hands from keyboard to mouse is annoying (there are probably keyboard shortcuts for navigating to the _Servers_ view , but that is still very inconvenient)

Comment: I set up a short-cut to "show servers" cmd + option + s then use the publish command cmd + option + p.  Then you add a short-cut to activate editor cmd + option + a.  To publish and go back to your editor  hold down cmd + option and just press s p a and your back to the editor with published code.